# Working with Xamarn android and SQLite browser

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin

I'm new to Xamarn and C#, and I tried to make an app with a database. 
And I try to select every row at the table and it worked. 
But when I tried to insert no errors show up but and **I can't see the new row that I added on SQLite browser**.
Also when I tried to select all the row the new did show up :).

I'm trying to make a database where anyone adds something they can see it more like store if someone adds item everyone can see it.

one more thing I always get this error when I try to select a table
Unhandled Exception:  Android.Database.Sqlite.SQLiteException:  occurred
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYyxM.png)

this my connection

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Database.Sqlite;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Java.Interop;
using Java.Lang;
using SQLite;
using Boolean = System.Boolean;
using Byte = System.Byte;
using SQLiteException = SQLite.SQLiteException;

namespace AppDatabase.Resources
{
    public class DBdiagnoseX : SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        private static readonly string DB_path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        private static string DB_name = "Diagnose.db";
        private static int VERSION = 1;
        public Context context;

        public DBdiagnoseX(Context context) :base(context, DB_name, null, VERSION)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }


        public string GetSqlPath()
        {
            return Path.Combine(DB_path, DB_name);
        }

        public override SQLiteDatabase WritableDatabase
        {
            get
            {
                return CreateSQLiteDB();
            }
        }

        private SQLiteDatabase CreateSQLiteDB()
        {
            SQLiteDatabase sqliteDB=null;
            string path = GetSqlPath();
            Stream streamSQLite = null;
            FileStream streamWriter = null;
            Boolean IsSQLiteInit = false;
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(path))
                    IsSQLiteInit = true;
                else
                {
                    streamSQLite = context.Resources.OpenRawResource(Resource.Raw.Diagnose);
                    streamWriter = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                    if(streamSQLite!=null && streamWriter != null)
                    {
                        if(CopySQLiteDB(streamSQLite,streamWriter))
                            IsSQLiteInit = true;
                    }
                }

                if (IsSQLiteInit)
                    sqliteDB =SQLiteDatabase.OpenDatabase(path, null, DatabaseOpenFlags.OpenReadonly);
            }
            catch{ }
            return sqliteDB;
        }
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: My question about the **error on the picture**and how to make database where if someone insert in to it, the other can see it

Comment: first, don't post errors as images.  Second, "others can see it" - what does that mean?  The db is stored on the device, only users of the device can access it.  If you want multiple users to share a db, then it needs to be stored on a server.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYyxM.png   the link for the images." others "I mean other users of the app. **any recommendation to what the best server to use** thanks a lot